# DataTable not binding to DataGrid in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm, datagrid

Can't figure out why my DataGrid isn't populating when I fill it's binded DataTable. I've checked other Stackoverflow posts but nothing seems to solve my problem. I know that my DataTable is getting filled up because the row count is over 50. The method that fills the DataTable (ReturnOperators) is sucessfully getting called (It's when the SelectedItem in a listbox is changed)

Here is my code:

Xaml:

```
                 <DataGrid x:Name="dgOperators"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding DtOperators}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                      Background="#0d0d0d"
                      Foreground="White"
                      Margin="10"
                     Grid.Row="1"
                  IsReadOnly="True" />
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

private ViewModel vm;

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vm = new ViewModel();
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
private DataTable dtOperators;

    public DataTable DtOperators
    {
        get { return dtOperators; }
        set
        {
            dtOperators = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DtOperators");
        }
    }

    public void ReturnOperators()
    {

        string query = "My SQL Query Here";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DtOperators.Clear();
            adapter.Fill(DtOperators);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your ViewModel inherit from the interface (INotifyPropertyChanged) and override the PropertyChangedEventHandler? I can't quite tell from the ViewModel code you've provided, is your OnPropertyChanged event successfully firing?

Comment: Yes. ViewModel Inherits from ViewModelBase which implements INotifyPropertyChanged. It'ss working on other properties in my ViewModel.

Comment: @JEllery I've managed to get it to work (Partially). adapter.Fill() doesn't set DtOperators for some reason. I fill a secondary DataTable 'dt' and then have DtOperators = dt and it works. Not sure why I have to do that though...

Comment: DtOperators is probably still null at the time you attempt to fill it. In your ViewModel constructor instantiate the DataTable (i.e. DtOperators = new DataTable();)

Comment: @JEllery I was already calling DtOperators = new DataTable(); in my constructor

Comment: `adapter.Fill(DtOperators);` does *obviously* not assign a new value to the `DtOperators` property. Hence the property setter and `OnPropertyChanged("DtOperators")` is of course not called.

Comment: @Clemens explain why please?

Comment: Why what? It does not assign a new value. C# basics. Use your debugger, put a breakpoint in the property setter, and notice that it isn't hit.

Comment: Yes @Clemens I found out the setter wasn't being called when I used the debugger. That's what lead me to my solution. I am a rookie, which is why I'm asking a question which seems obvious to you. Would you like to offer a more eloquent solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a property value to a method like

```
adapter.Fill(DtOperators)
```

does obviously not assign a new value to the property. Hence the DtOperators setter was not triggered.

I amended my ReturnOperators() to the following. By filling another DataTable and then setting DtOperators to that DataTable, it worked.

```
public void ReturnOperators()
    {            
        string query = @"SELECT TOP 1000 [Store],[opid],[last4],[repeatserve_Count] FROM [POS].[dbo].[LVRC_Summary] WHERE repeatserve_count > 5";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DtOperators.Clear();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            DtOperators = dt;
        }
    }
```